# JButton and next/previous object of treemap

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, treemap

I have this problem:

1) There are objects placed in the TreeMap through the JTextField. (Phonebook-like program).

2)There are buttons that implement view of available records in TreeMap. 
When you click on these buttons next / previous available objects of TreeMap displaying in JTextField. (scroll through the available records).

I tried this code, but it didn't work :/

```
btn[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     Iterator iter = tree.keySet().iterator();
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (iter.hasNext()){
         String str = iter.next().toString();
         fldFio.setText(str);
         fldNumber.setText(tree.get(str));
         }
      }
});
```

I added this line in method actionPerformed as a first line:

```
System.out.println(iter1.hasNext());
```

Result is "false", if it will be anyhow helpful.

Comment: empty treeMap at the time of adding the listener? Just guessing, though, no way to tell without seeing more code, preferably an SSCCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I released this thing using methods from NavigableMap. Thx all for help:

```
btn[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       String str;
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (tree.size() != 0){
               if ((str)==null){
                   str = tree.firstKey();
                   } else {
                   fldFio.setText(str);
                   fldNumber.setText(tree.get(str));
                   str = tree.higherKey(str);   
                   }
          }
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using another `Iterator` `iter1` in your application. To navigate through your `TreeMap` you need to use the iterator defined in your `ActionListener`:

```
 if (iter.hasNext()){
    String str = iter.next().toString();
    ...
```

Comment: It's just typo in question-post code. Sorry for my inattention.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to move the iterator inside the "actionPerformed()" method:

```
btn[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     Iterator iter = tree.keySet().iterator();
     if (iter.hasNext()){
     String str = iter1.next().toString();
     fldFio.setText(str);
     fldNumber.setText(tree.get(str));
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried it at first, but as you can see from code, in this case every time I press the button iterator will initialize again, so value appearing in JTextField always will be a value of first element in TreeMap (first iteration).